# List of files of saved to the internal storage

Tags: android

My android application is saving some stats to internal storage. Each file name is in the format of "appname-currentDate"

I was wondering:

1. When I save to internal storage, is there a specific folder assigned to my app, or are my files saved along with files from other applications in the same directory.
2. Is there a way to know the list of files saved by my application to the internal storage

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) Depends on which method you use to get the file handle. Normally files are stored in an application specific directory, eg. **/data/data/[your.package.name]/**. The files in that directory are only readable by your application.

2) Use the **getFilesDir()** method in your **Activity** to get a **File** handle and use the **listFiles()** on it to get an array of **File** representing all files in your application data folder.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 4):

```
1-When I save to internal storage, is there a specific folder assigned to my app, or are my files saved along with files from other applications in the same direcotry.
```

By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
   user).

And files are stored in `/data/data/<package_name>/files` directory.
   Particular for your application package.

```
2- Is there a way to know the list of files saved by my application to the internal storage.
```

use method **getFilesDir()**

Gets the absolute path to the filesystem directory where your internal files are saved.

For more information look at [Android - Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Tahnk you +1, as I was looking for the function that actually list the files which was answered in another answer.. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your files will be saved in **data/data/your.package.com** this folder. **your.package.com** is your package name.

You can see that in ddms. If you use eclipse and run emulator or device you can see your files in eclipse -> ddms tab

[image]

Comment: If device is not rooted then you can't see it.

Comment: I am looking for programmatic way. Also my device is not rooted. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

use this method to get array of internal files stored by application.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList()

more information here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal