# Accessing Data Saved to Internal Storage on Android Device

Tags: java, android, csv, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and have gone through a ton of tutorials. I have a working accelerometer and want to save the data to a .csv file. 
My code below works because when I use the emulator I am able to export the .csv file , with the correct data, to my desktop and open it. I have these two permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When I go into the file explorer on my device using apps such as Astro or ES and go to `data/data/` I do not even see my package there even though the app works on my phone. Is there something you need to do to have the package show up in the file explorer? I would like to get the data from the .csv from my phone.

I was hoping someone had some in

```
String Entry = x.getText().toString() + ", "
        + y.getText().toString() + ", " +
        z.getText().toString() + "\n";
try{
    FileOutputStream outPut = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    outPut.write(Entry.getBytes());
    outPut.close();
}catch(Exception err){
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String FILENAME = "keyboardTest.csv";
        File file = new File (dir, FILENAME)
       try {   
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                out.write(Entry.getBytes());
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now I am able to access the file on my phone

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @TodorKostov edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access these files(inside /data/data) until you are running the app on an emulator or you are running the app on a rooted device.

please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239319/6646796) for more details.

**EDIT**

You can do the following to save files in an accessible location:-

```
/*get the path to internal storage*/
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
/*create the app folder and check if it exists or not*/
File curDir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+appName);
if(!curDir.exists()){
        curDir.mkdirs();
}
/*create the file*/
File f = new File(curDir+"/"+fileName);
f.createNewFile();
/*code to edit the file*/
```

Comment: @csciBeginner you can check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

Comment: I thought you can't access a database. I thought a csv or txt would be fine because it would be placed in the files folder. And on Android's sight they recommend storing data the way I used

Comment: If you are testing your app on a device running Android M then you will have to ask for the permission during runtime and you may also have to give a path to store the file. You will need to use  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get a path and save files there

Comment: @shrijit can you show me how to implement that? Where would I add that into my existing code?

Comment: @csciBeginner i added the code. Comment if it did not work out.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I put the code I used in the edit of my post. Thanks.